# how to fit canvas drawing inside canvas window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```js
 var $canvasDiv = $('#canvasdiv');
 var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
 var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var c1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
 canvas.height = $canvasDiv.innerHeight();
 canvas.width = $canvasDiv.innerWidth();
 c.font = "15px Arial";
 
function degToRad(angle){
 var pi = Math.PI;
    return angle * (pi/180);
}
 
function crtanjeGrede(l)
{
 var oslonac1 = parseInt(l) + 30;

 c.beginPath();
 c.fillRect(30,30,l,5); //pravougaonik koji pocinje na x30 y30, duzine l koja je unos i debljine 5

 c.beginPath();
 c.moveTo(oslonac1,35);
 c.lineTo(oslonac1 + 25,45);
 c.lineTo(oslonac1 - 25,45);
 c.lineTo(oslonac1,35);
 c.moveTo(oslonac1 + 25, 50);
 c.lineTo(oslonac1 - 25, 50);
 c.stroke();
 
 c.beginPath();
 c.moveTo(30,35);
 c.lineTo(55,45);
 c.lineTo(5,45);
 c.lineTo(30,35);
  
 c.moveTo(30, 70);
 c.lineTo(30, 400);
 c.moveTo(oslonac1 , 70);
 c.lineTo(oslonac1 , 400);
 
 c.moveTo(30, 120);
 c.lineTo(oslonac1, 120);
 c.fillText("Fa",5,124);
 
 c.moveTo(30, 190);
 c.lineTo(oslonac1,190);
 c.fillText("Ft",5,194);
 
 c.moveTo(30, 270);
 c.lineTo(oslonac1, 270);
 c.fillText("Ma",5,274);
 
 c.closePath();
 c.strokeStyle = 'black';
 c.stroke();
 
}

// ako je pravac true znaci da je po Y, false je po x
// ako je smer true znaci da je na poz stranu, false je na negativnu
function crtanjeSile(n, pravac, smer)
{
  //pravac
 if (pravac){
  var naptka = parseInt(n) + 30;
  if (smer){
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(naptka , 24);
   c.lineTo(naptka + 3, 16);
   c.lineTo(naptka - 3 , 16);
   c.lineTo(naptka , 24);
   c.fillStyle ="#000000";
   c.fill();
   
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(naptka , 0);
   c.lineTo(naptka , 25);
   c.stroke();
   c.closePath();
   
  } else {
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(naptka , 41);
   c.lineTo(naptka + 3, 49);
   c.lineTo(naptka - 3 , 49);
   c.lineTo(naptka , 41);
   c.fillStyle ="#000000";
   c.fill();
   
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(naptka, 41);
   c.lineTo(naptka, 66);
   c.stroke();
   c.closePath();
  }
  
 }else{

}}
 
function crtanjeSile1(b, pravac1, smer1){ 
 if(pravac1){
  var naptka = parseInt(b) + 30;
  if(smer1 == false){ //treba samodorada da li se sila crta iznad ili ispod X ose
  //var naptka = parseInt(n) + 30;
   c.beginPath(); //strelica nadesno
   c.moveTo(naptka - 1, 25);
   c.lineTo(naptka - 9, 22);
   c.lineTo(naptka - 9, 28);
   c.lineTo(naptka - 1, 25);
   c.fillStyle ="#000000";
   c.fill();
   
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(naptka - 1, 25);
   c.lineTo(naptka - 26, 25);
   c.strokeStyle = 'black';
   c.stroke();
   c.closePath()
  }else{
   c.beginPath(); //strelica u levo
   c.moveTo(naptka + 1 , 40);
   c.lineTo(naptka + 9 , 37);
   c.lineTo(naptka + 9 , 43);
   c.lineTo(naptka + 1 , 40);
   c.fillStyle ="#000000";
   c.fill();
   
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(naptka + 1, 40);
   c.lineTo(naptka + 26, 40);
   c.stroke();
   c.closePath();
  }
 }else{
  c.beginPath();
  c.closePath();
 }
}

//crtanje gerbera je bilo ovde
 
function aksijalnesile(l, a, intX, X){ //crtanje aksijalnih sila
 var polaznatka = parseInt(l) + 30;
 var duzina = parseInt(a) + 30;
 
 if(pravac1){
  if(smer1){
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(polaznatka, 120);
   //c.fillRect(polaznatka,120,duzina - polaznatka, -10);  ova funkcija radi isto
   c.lineTo(polaznatka, 110); 
   c.lineTo(duzina, 110);
   c.lineTo(duzina, 120); 
   c.closePath();
   c.fill();
   c.textAlign = 'center';
   c.fillText(intX.toFixed(2), polaznatka, 105);
   c.textAlign = 'end';
   c.fillText(intX.toFixed(2), duzina - 2, 105);
   c.stroke();
  }else{
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(polaznatka, 120); 
   c.lineTo(polaznatka, 130);
   c.lineTo(30, 130);
   c.lineTo(30, 120);
   c.closePath();
   c.fill();
   c.textAlign = 'center';
   c.fillText(intX.toFixed(2), polaznatka, 145);
   c.textAlign = 'start';
   //c.fillText(intX.toFixed(2), 30 + 1, 135);
   c.stroke();
  }
  }else{ 
  
  }
}

function transverzalnesile(l, a, intY, Y){ //crtanje transverzalnih sila
 var polaznatka = parseInt(l) + 30;
 var duzina = parseInt(a) + 30;
 
 if(pravac){
  if(smer){
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(polaznatka, 190); 
   c.lineTo(polaznatka, 180);
   c.lineTo(30, 180);
   c.lineTo(30, 190);
   c.closePath();
   c.fill();
   c.textAlign = 'center';
   c.fillText(intY.toFixed(2), polaznatka, 215);
   c.textAlign = 'start';
   //c.fillText(intX.toFixed(2), 30 + 1, 135);
   c.stroke();
  }else{
   c.beginPath();
   c.moveTo(polaznatka, 190);
   //c.fillRect();  ova funkcija radi isto
   c.lineTo(polaznatka, 180); 
   c.lineTo(duzina, 180);
   c.lineTo(duzina, 190); 
   c.closePath();
   c.fill();
   c.textAlign = 'center';
   c.fillText(intY.toFixed(2), polaznatka, 175);
   c.textAlign = 'end';
   c.fillText(intY.toFixed(2), duzina - 2, 175);
   c.stroke();
  }
  }else{ 
  
  }
}


$("#sub").click(function() {
 //debugger;
 
 var duzina = $("#Duzina").val();
 var inten = $("#inten").val();
 var naptka = $("#naptka").val();
 var napugao = $("#napugao").val();
 var gerber1 = $("#gerber1").val();
 var gerber2 = $("#gerber2").val();
 
 var inten = parseInt(inten , 10);
 var napugao = parseInt(napugao, 10 );
 var intX = inten * Math.cos(degToRad(napugao)).toFixed(3); // funkcija .toFixed() zaokruzuije na 3 decimale da bi sin 0 bio 0, a ne !=0
 if (intX !== 0){
  pravac1 = true;
  if (intX > 0){
   smer1 = true;
  }else{
   smer1 = false; 
  }
 }else{
  pravac1 = false;
 }
 crtanjeSile1(naptka, pravac1, ); //skinut parametar smer1 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 
 var intY = inten * Math.sin(degToRad(napugao)).toFixed(3); // funkcija .toFixed() zaokruzuije na 3 decimale da bi sin 0 bio 0, a ne !=0
 if (intY !== 0){
  pravac = true;
  if (intY > 0){
   smer = true;
  }else{
   smer = false; 
  }
  //crtanjeSile(naptka, pravac, smer);
 }else{
  pravac = false;
 }
 crtanjeSile(naptka, pravac, smer);

 var Y = inten * Math.sin(degToRad(napugao)).toFixed(3);
 var X = inten * Math.cos(degToRad(napugao)).toFixed(3);
 
 var a = parseInt(naptka) + 30;
 
 function move(y, naptka)
{
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(naptka + 30, y + 50);
    c.lineTo(naptka + 50, y + 50);
    c.stroke();
}
  

 
 crtanjeGrede(duzina);
 move(Y, naptka);
 aksijalnesile(naptka, duzina, intX, X);
 transverzalnesile(naptka, duzina, intY, Y);
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#logo{
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 1px;
}

.gore{
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 3px;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 
}

.unos{
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 3px;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
}

.unos2{
 margin-top: 20px;
}

form{
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.imput{
 width= 100%;
}

.forma{
 padding: 3px;
}

input{
 margin-top: 4px;
}

.floutleft{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 
}

.sire{
 width: 300px;
}

.tr{
 width: 150px;
}

canvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="gore">
        <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo" alt="logo masinca" width="60" height="60">
    </div>
    
 
<center>
 <form action="" class="unos">
  <table class="unos2">
    <tr><td style>duzina grede [mm]:</td> <td><input type="text" name="Duzina" id="Duzina" placeholder="duzina grede" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td>intenzitet sile [N]:</td> <td><input type="text" name="inten" id="inten" placeholder="intenzitet sile"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>napadna tacka [mm]:</td> <td><input type="text" name="naptka" id="naptka" placeholder="napadna tacka" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td>napadni ugao [°]:</td> <td><input type="text" name="napugao" id="napugao" placeholder="napadni ugao" ></td></tr>
  </table> 
  <table>
    <td><input class="" type="button" name="sub" id="sub" value="Draw" class="imput"></td>
  </table>
 </form>
 
<div id="canvasdiv" class="unos3" style="margin: 5px; height: 80%; width: 80%;">
    <canvas id="mycanvas" style="border: none;"></canvas>
</div>


</center>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

i need help with my image fitting in canvas width in html page.
i defined canvas width 100%, but div width 80% (see picture) and the image inside the canvas is defined by user in the HTML.

The drawing could be width 10px, but also could be 1000px and i want to fit it inside the desired canvas so that it could be visible at any defined width (not too small, but not big enough to go over the desired width as shown in second picture)

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJFA5.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNOB3.png)

it would be the best if i could do the scaling separately so that i could fix the size of the side elements (rounded with red color on the third picture) and only to manipulate with the blue element (see third pic).

[third picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS2TQ.png)

Comment: We can't really help unless we have the code for it.

Comment: @Chipster whole code is written now.